# Serve image with PHP script vs direct loading an image

Tags: php

I want to monitor how often some external images are loaded.
So my idea is instead of giving a uri directly like this:

```
www.site.com/image1.jpg
```

I can create a PHP script which reads the image, so I built a PHP file and my HTML would look like this:

```
<img src="www.site.com/serveImage.php?img=image1.jpg">
```

but I don't know how to read the image from disk and return it. Would I return a byte array or set the content type?

Kind regards,
Michel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set the content type:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Then you load the image and output it like this:

```
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['img']);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: imagecreatefromjpeg + imagejpeg might be a bit overkill (anc CPU-consumming) if you just want to send the data from a file -- advantage I see is making sure you really load image ; but there are probably other ways to be sure of that (like allowing only one directory, that only contains images)

Comment: readfile is better if you are just gonna send the image as is.

Answer (score 42):

Sending images through a script is nice for other things like resizing and caching on demand.

As answered by Pascal MARTIN the function `readfile` and these headers are the requirements:

- Content-Type

  - The mime type of this content
  - Example: `header('Content-Type: image/gif');`
  - See the function [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)
  - Types

    - `image/gif`
    - `image/jpeg`
    - `image/png`

But beside the obvious content-type you should also look at other headers such as:

- Content-Length

  - The length of the response body in octets (8-bit bytes)
  - Example: `header('Content-Length: 348');`
  - See the function [`filesize`](http://php.net/filesize)
  - Allows the connectio to be better used.
- Last-Modified

  - The last modified date for the requested object, in RFC 2822 format
  - Example: `header('Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT');`
  - See the function [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it into the required RFC 2822 format

    - Example: `header('Last-Modified: '.date(DATE_RFC2822, filemtime($filename)));`
  - You can exit the script after sending a 304 if the file modified time is the same.
- status code

  - Example: `header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");`
  - you can exit now and not send the image one more time

For last modified time, look for this in `$_SERVER`

- If-Modified-Since

  - Allows a 304 Not Modified to be returned if content is unchanged
  - Example: `If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT`
  - Is in `$_SERVER` with the key `http_if_modified_since`

[List of HTTP header responses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields)

Comment: Here is a nice code that help to implement all theses headers: [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/intelligent-php-cache-control/)

Answer (score 23):

To achieve something like this, your script will need to :

- send the right headers, which depend on the type of the image : image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, ...
- send the data of the image
- making sure **nothing** else is sent *(no white space, no nothing)*

This is done with the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, with some code like this :

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
```

Or

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

or whatever, depending on the type of the image.

To send the data of the image, you can use the [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/readfile) function :

> Reads a file and writes it to the
>   output buffer.

This way, in one function, you both read the file, and output its content.

As a sidenote :

- you must put some security in place, to ensure users can't request anything they want via your script : you must make sure it only serves images, from the directory you expect ; nothing like `serveImage.php?file=/etc/passwd` should be OK, for instance.
- If you're just willing to get the number of times a file was loaded each day, parsing Apache's log file might be a good idea (via a batch run by cron each day at 00:05, that parses the log of the day before, for instance) ; you won't have real-time statistics, but it will require less resources on your server *(no PHP to serve static files)*

Comment: thanks for the sidenote: •you must put some security in place, to ensure users can't request anything they want via your script : you must make sure it only serves images, from the directory you expect ; nothing like serveImage.php?file=/etc/passwd should be OK, for instance.

Answer (score 12):

I use the "passthru" function to call "cat" command, like this:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
passthru('cat /path/to/image/file.jpg');
```

Works on Linux. Saves resources.

Comment: Excellent solution. Just keep in mind, that some hosts disable the `passthru` command for security reasons

Answer (score 9):

Instead of changing the direct image url in the HTML, you can put a line in the Apache configuration or `.htaccess` to rewrite all the requests of images in a directory to a php script. Then in that script you can make use of the request headers and the `$_server` array to process the request and serve the file.

First in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ serve.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpeg$ serve.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ serve.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ serve.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.bmp$ serve.php [NC]
```

The script `serve.php` must be in the same directory as `.htaccess`. You will probably write something like this:

```
<?php
$filepath=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$filepath='.'.$filepath;
if (file_exists($filepath))
{
touch($filepath,filemtime($filepath),time()); // this will just record the time of access in file inode. you can write your own code to do whatever
$path_parts=pathinfo($filepath);
switch(strtolower($path_parts['extension']))
{
case "gif":
header("Content-type: image/gif");
break;
case "jpg":
case "jpeg":
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
break;
case "png":
header("Content-type: image/png");
break;
case "bmp":
header("Content-type: image/bmp");
break;
}
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
header("Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Mar 2004 06:32:31 GMT");
readfile($filepath);

}
else
{
 header( "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("404_files.jpg"));
 header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
 header("Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Mar 2004 06:32:31 GMT");
 readfile("404_files.jpg");
}
/*
By Samer Mhana
www.dorar-aliraq.net
*/
?>
```

(This script can be improved!)

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you want to the user to see a real filename instead of your scriptname when the user RMC's on the image and selects "Save As", you'll need to also set this header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename=$filename');
```

Comment: this can also be solved with redirecting in apache (virtual host or .htaccess) to the script file. so /img/somefile_small.jpg get internal redirect to showimage.php

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off examining your server access logs for this. Running all images through php might put a bit of load on your server.

Comment: hmm, that would surely do the trick. i'll save that when the load becomes an issue.

Comment: In addition, running them through a PHP script will affect client-side caching, which could in fact increase the read load.

Comment: @rob: that has nothing to do with running it through a script, but forgetting to send the right headers. I have the 2 best ones in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I serve my images with readfile as well, but I have gone the extra mile both for security and extra functionality.

I have a database set up which stores the image id, its dimensions and file extension. This also means that images need to be uploaded (allowing optional resizing), so I only use the system for content and not images needed for the website itself (like backgrounds or sprites).

It also does a very good job at making sure you can only request images.

So, for serving the simplified workflow would be like this (cannot post production code here):

1) get the ID of the requested image

2) Look it up in the database

3) Throw headers based on the extension ("jpg" gets remapped to "jpeg" on upload)

4) `readfile("/images/$id.$extension");`

5) Optionally, protect /images/ dir so it cannot be indexed (not a problem in my own system as it maps URLS like */image/view/11* to something like */index.php?module=image&action=view&id=11*)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good answers above, but none of them provide working code that you can use in your PHP app. I've set mine up so that I lookup the name of the image in a database table based off a different identifier. *The client never sets the name of the file to download as this is a security risk.*

Once the image name is found, I explode it to obtain the extension. This is important to know what type of header to serve based off the image type (i.e. png, jpg, jpeg, gif, etc.). I use a switch to do this for security reasons and to convert jpg -> jpeg for the proper header name. I've included a few additional headers in my code that ensure the file is not cached, that revalidation is required, to change the name (otherwise it will be the name of the script that is called), and finally to read the file from the server and transmit it.

I like this method since it never exposes the directory or actual file name. Be sure you authenticate the user before running the script if you are trying to do this securely.

```
$temp = explode('.', $image_filename);
$extension = end($temp);    // jpg, jpeg, gif, png - add other flavors based off your use case

switch ($extension) {
    case "jpg":
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "gif":
    case "png":
        header('Content-type: image/'.$extension);
        break;
    default:
        die;    // avoid security issues with prohibited extensions
}

header('Content-Disposition: filename=photo.'.$extension);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
readfile('../SECURE_DIRECTORY/'.$image_filename);
```

PHP 8 lets you use the match feature, which will further optimize the code by getting rid of the switch and ugly looking nested cases.