# Check permission of users for viewing static files in apache server with php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions

I have implemented a php website that has some users.
I want to manage their access to static files.

In addition, I have a function in a file `permissions.php` that gets a url (e.g. `/images/secret.jpg`) and checks the it's permission for the current logged in user.

I think I need to add something to .htaccess file that for every request, first call my function in `permissions.php` then serve the file if it returns true otherwise return 404.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to set the permissions for all the file to be protected, and use PHP to fetch the file and [serve it by modifying the headers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-image). This way, you can check if the user has permission to the file, and if they have, the PHP code will fetch the file and serve it to them.

(Incidentally, there's an answer on the linked question that changes .htaccess. I prefer not mess with that myself).

Comment: Thank you, but how can I realize the requested urls?

Comment: You can block off direct access, and instead list down all the files that you want to grant access using coding.