# PHP: display a dynamic image from serial (char) imagedata

Tags: php, image, serial-port

I am looking for an easy way to display dynamic image content received via serial on a website  preferably using php.

I'm a C++ programmer used to use OpenCV, now i have found that there are ways to integrate OpenCV into PHP, but this doesn't look very simple and its probably way to overpowered for my application.

To further draw a picture of what I am trying to accomplish, this is my application:

I am building a coffee-table-tennis-led-screen. Using 32x16 LEDs, a multiplexer an Arduino and a glass coffee table. My server is going to run a Pong server program which is displayed on the coffee table. To play you can either use the pot-meters on the coffee table or log into a website and play "online" either against someone at the coffee table or against someone else online.

So the only thing this website is going to have to do is display serial information in an image at framerates of about 10 fps and send some data back (2 position bytes per frame) via serial to the server application.

Should I look into (as I see it) the heavier stuff like WebGL or something? Or are there way simpler PHP functions to do such a thing?

PS: Serial communication itself I have done before, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: sounds interesting :-) haven't understood your question, though (no native speaker). Do you want to create a gif/png/jpg with PHP? From what kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GD functions in the PHP manual, especially the [imagecreatefromstring function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Comment: This looks good, but how will i go about auto refreshing the image at the specified rate? Because reloading the whole page probably takes too long right?

Comment: See the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-image. You don't need a whole page, you can just have PHP serve an image (bitmap would be best I think, or maybe gif)