# issues using fancybox to display blob images

Tags: php, fancybox, blob

I am trying to use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display images. My images are blobs inside a mysql db.

Here is the html/php I am using:

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="g1" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($pic['screenshot']); ?>"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($pic['screenshot']); ?>" width="150px" height="250px"/></a>
```

this works but I have this weird flickering ghost image problem when the page loads and when I move my mouse over the image.

Answer (score 3):

Image display section:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="blob:http://localhost:8080/a71e1fb6-8482-49cf-88fa-a29dfc71e39e">
    <img src="blob:http://localhost:8080/a71e1fb6-8482-49cf-88fa-a29dfc71e39e"/>
</a>
```

Set document type for fancybox by this way (When page load):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({type : 'image'});
}
```

And success come.

When using fancy box with `pdf` or other filetypes (not image), we set other appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know what you did was possible.  I think a better approach would be to create a script to dynamically server your images...

so the image src would be "image.php?id=123" and then you would have the image.php serving script ie...

[Serve image with PHP script vs direct loading an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-image)

I don't know enough about your app but is storing images in the db a good idea..seems like they are going to make the db big fast.

Comment: unfortunately i have no other option other than storing it in the db. I have also done what you suggest but when I put that into <a href and click the image, it opens a new window instead of using fancybox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment so I'm going to put my 2 cents here. Hope it helps.

blob storage may not be fully supported on mobile devices.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

> so the image src would be "image.php?id=123" and then you would have the image.php serving script ie...

That's a really good idea except for in my case we are using Web API with MVC/ADFS authentication model. Web API is a stateless web service so that option doesn't always work everywhere. To make it work we would have to allow anonymous access to that API call and that could be a security risk depending on the data.