# htaccess - Allow directory access for specific url

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have a directory called 'files/private' with images in and it has a .htaccess file in it with "Deny from all" so that no-one can access the contents of the directory through a browser.

However I want to allow access to the images if the user is logged into an admin area.  Is there a way I can allow access for a specific URL?  If they are logged into the admin area request will be coming from www.mydomain.com/admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow access if the referer is from `www.mydomain.com/admin` but *it is extremely easy to spoof the referer header in a request* and therefore this isn't a very secure way to protect your private files. Something that you can do is have the admin area server the images directly, something like (in php): [Serve image with PHP script vs direct loading an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-image)

This way, the script can ensure that the right credentials are there before it reads the image file and outputs it directly to the browser. You'll just have to make sure images linked from the admin area go through the same script.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is a lot better