# GD Image resize and Header(Content-type)

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the correct use of the Header(content-type:image/png) .I have an upload script that uploads and resizes correctly,with or without the header, but it seems like its recommended to have the header .Problem is that with the header, once the script completes, it throws a 'broken img' icon in the top left corner of the window and exits the script. How do I make it behave differently like if I want to redirect to a new page. Adding Header(location:...) at the end of the script doesn't seem to make a difference. ANY Help is appreciated.

```
<?PHP


  /*image resize with Imagick*/
  function imageResize($image){
   /*call to imagick class and resize functions will go here*/

   echo 'the image to be resized is : '.$image;
   $newImage=new Imagick();
   $newImage->readImage($image);
   $newImage->resizeImage(1024,768,imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
   $newImage->writeImage('myImage.png');
   $newImage->clear();
   $newImage->destroy();

 }

 /*image resize with GD image functions*/


 function imgResize($image){
 header('Content-Type: image/png');

 $newWidth='1024';
 $newHeight='768';

 $size=getimagesize($image);

 $width=$size[0];
 $height=$size[1];



 //return $width;
 $dest=imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);
 $source=imagecreatefrompng($image);
 imagecopyresized($dest,$source,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height );
 return imagepng($dest,'./users/uploads/newimage.png'); 
 imagedestroy($dest);

 }

 /*Function that actually does the upload*/

 function file_upload(){ 

  if(!empty( $_FILES) ){
  print_r($_FILES);

  echo '<hr>';

  $tmpFldr=$_FILES['upFile']['tmp_name'];
  $fileDest='./users/uploads/'.$_FILES['upFile']['name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFldr,$fileDest)){

      echo 'Congratulations, your folder was uploaded successfully <br><br>';

      }
    else{
     echo 'Your file failed to upload<br><br>';

     }
     return $fileDest; 
    } else{die( 'Nothing to upload');}




 } /*End file upload function */ 



$fileLocation=file_upload();

echo 'location of the new file is : '.$fileLocation.'<hr>';

$newImage=imgResize($fileLocation);



?>
```

Comment: You are setting a content-type header for a PNG image but are outputting text, your browser doesn't know what to do with all that and thinks that the text is actually a broken image, and displays the appropriate icon. Either remove that header, or serve an actual image instead of the text.

Comment: thanks Andre..it does work without header. I think i'm more confused about the importance of the header and if GD resize needs it specified.In other words..am i going to find myself having to put it back in at some point. This code will eventially be part of an image handling class

Comment: The header is only needed when you want to [serve an image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1353866/2629998).

Comment: Thanks!! for that clarification and the link...that is now crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't serve an image and serve a redirect at the same time. If you want to output a PNG image then you output the Content-Type header and that's exclusive of the Location header.