# What is the Most Secure php file upload method that can handle all filetypes?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I am trying to develop a small social network and would like to know if the following approach would be enough to make my 'file upload handling script' as secure as possible. I aim to allow my users to upload images[jpeg,jpg,png,gif], videos[3gp,wma,mp4] and mp3 files. I have gone through many of the questions here at SO, but most of them seem to deal with image uploading in detail and not videos and mp3. I would like to know what more i can do anything to make the script the msot secure uploading script available. [yes, i am pretty paranoid about security and would definitely want my site to be known for it's security rather than it's speed].
My current approach is as follows:

- check if user is registered (by checking the session)
- check if file is uploaded without errors
- check if file size is in permissible range
- sanitize the file name
- get the file extension and check if it is an allowed extension
- get the mime type and check if it is an allowed mime type
- generate new random file name
- set .htaccess rules for a folder outside public_html and use it to
  store the uploaded files
- use move_uploaded_file()
- use chmod() to set '0644' as permission for the uploaded file

In the .htaccess file the following will be added:

```
 SetHandler none
    SetHandler default-handler
    Options -ExecCGI
    php_flag engine off

ForceType application/octet-stream
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.jpe?g$">
    ForceType image/jpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.gif$">
    ForceType image/gif
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.png$">
    ForceType image/png
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.mp3$">
    ForceType audio/mpeg
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.mp4$">
    ForceType video/mp4
</FilesMatch>
```

The code that i am trying is as follows :

```
$fileInput = $_FILES['image'];
$sizeLimit="4000";
if($fileInput['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK && isset($fileInput['tmp_name'])){
if($fileInput['size'] < $sizeLimit){
$cleanedName=stripslashes($fileInput['name']); //cleaning file name
$checking = pathinfo($cleanedName); //finding extension
$ext=$checking['extension'];
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // find mime type
$mimetype =  finfo_file($finfo, $fileInput['tmp_name']);
finfo_close($finfo);
.
.
.//generate random name and use move_uploaded_file() and chmod()
}
}
```

Is this approach enough to keep my site secure,or are there some glaring flaws in this method?. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want to be more secure, make sure you have SSL. Regarding the uploads themselves, a file is just a file no matter its type, and larger files or files of a particular type are not harder or less secure per se.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks. Yes, i will definitely be using SSL. I have noticed that most users on SO mostly suggest using GD to verify if an upload is an image, but is there any such verification method for videos and audios to be more sure about the files?. Does my approach leave any gaping loopholes that could be easily manipulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the filename extension is recommended, although be aware that the mime type can easily be spoofed, so this is not a good check for security.

What you have so far is good, my additional tips would be:

- Virus scan all uploads - this is more to protect other users of your application rather than your server.
- Store images outside of the web root totally, and use [an approach such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353850/413180) to proxy the files to be served. This has the advantage that any additional permission checks can be carried out in code (so Bob can't download Alice's files) and as the files are accessed as data, there is no chance of execution.
- Serve files with the [`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) header to prevent any [`XSS`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks via IE's mime sniffing.
- Store images using server generated names. For example, you could name each file after the primary key of its database entry. This will mitigate against any [directory traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) attacks ([like this one](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/10/directory-traversal-via-php-multi-file-uploads/)) and if a user does manage to upload something malicious they will be less likely to find it on the server.
- Load all images into an image library and resave them to ensure they don't have any [exploits embedded for popular browsers](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/14282/discuss).
- Have some sort of manual monitoring system in place to watch for any uploaded illegal content.
- Protect your form against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the wonderful tips..i plan on using clamAv to scan the files..I am hoping that session based csrf tokens will be enough to mitigate any csrf threats..

Comment: Yes, session based csrf Tokens are the way to go.