# Is it possible to trigger (to execute) a php file at the moment the user is accessing another file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

For example,
if a user is accessing an image file on my server, is it possible to execute another PHP file at the same time?

I want to record the ip, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` of the users who have accessed this image file. The difficult point is how to execute (or may say “trigger”) that PHP recording file at the time the user is accessing the image. I know I can read the content of the image to the PHP first then output it as an image and record the user's information meanwhile, but this method may occupy so much memory usage when the size of the image file is very large. For this reason, is it possible to make the user access the image file directly but also can trigger another PHP file at the same time?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  Any chance you could review the answers, and provide comments and/or upvote and accept as you deem appropriate?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accept!  Please let me know why my answer may be unsatisfactory to not warrant an upvote as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you just want to log record [`$remote_addr`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_variable_remote_addr), as well as [`$http_user_agent`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c#ngx_http_core_variables) and [`$http_accept_language`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#accept_language), you don't really have to use PHP at all — the whole procedure can be accomplished with a custom log format more elaborate than the [`combined`](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.c#ngx_http_combined_fmt) one, in both [nginx](http://ports.su/www/nginx) as well as [Apache](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd,-main).
- Additionally, you could also utilise the functionality of [`ngx_http_addition_module`](http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_addition_filter_module.c) to perform a subrequest before or after each other request, where you would do your logging, and supply nothing in return (such as not to actually corrupt the images).
- Alternatively, you could also have all requests go to PHP, and subsequently use [`X-Accel-Redirect`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.h#x_accel_redirect) with the value of the request, subsequently having nginx serve the image without the involvement of your php script, hence alleviating your memory-use concerns.

---

Reference Docs:

- - http://nginx.org/r/access_log
  - http://nginx.org/r/log_format
- - http://nginx.org/r/add_before_body
  - http://nginx.org/r/add_after_body
- - http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_ignore_headers
  - http://nginx.org/r/internal

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions

- tell apache to route to your index.php (or whatever) for every image request (rewrite all request to yourscript.php, process and route to the correct file/controller) exemple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9453207/4196542
- don't give real image url, and pass through a php controller like "/getImage.php?image=foo.png". Record the ip and all the data you want then serve the image.