# REST API with images

Tags: php, rest

I am in the process of putting together a REST API of an image application to be consumed by an Angular Frontend. The API is being put together using PHP. All of the images are securely stored outside of the webroot.

Problem is that I am converting all my images to base64, it increases the payload, in some cases I have 40 images display on a page, not uncommon to wait 30-40 seconds due to the huge payload.

What is the best practice for presenting images using REST API? I have searched round, there is nothing that exactly addresses the problem. Code below. The base64 images bloats the payload by an incredible amount. Any pointers please.

```
//create presentation array
$presentation_arr=array();
$presentation_arr["records"]=array();
$LargeImageName = $slideName;
$LargefileDir = $largefolder. $fileid . '/';
$Largefile = $LargefileDir . $LargeImageName;

if (file_exists($Largefile)){
    $b64largeImage = base64_encode(file_get_contents($Largefile));
    $datafullpath = 'data:image/jpg;base64,$b64image';
}

$presentation_item=array(
    "id" => $id,
    "smallimage" => $b64image,
    "largeimage" => $b64largeImage
);

array_push($presentation_arr["imagerecords"], $presentation_item);
```

Comment: It appears that all your API does is convert images to base64 - is that right?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt - Yes, stores the converted info into an array and pushes it into a JSON file on request. Problem is that the base64 info is humongous, thinking there must be a better way than what I am currently doing.

Comment: Your REST api can just return the images as-is, not packed in a JSON document. Why would you serve a JSON document and embed an image in it? It's not unlike somebody making a screenshot, printing it, taking a photo of it and then pasting it in a word document before sending it via email

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

- Create a "wrapper" endpoint that is just a proxy to the final image itself (e.g. does a `readfile()` internally, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353867/1364793)
- Host the images at a static, web accessible folder (or even consider S3 as a storage for static assets). Then, your main endpoint just returns publicly accessile URLs to those.

Comment: I think I like your second suggestion better. I have been thinking of S3, might ultimately go for that solution. I'll have to think of a security later to access the images.

Comment: I'm assuming the reason you're storing images outside web root is to avoid serving them directly so they can't be easily scraped. Note with the S3 approach, you can create expiring URLs.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - Correct, scrapping and other security concerns is why they are outside the web root.

Answer (score 0):

You write that you are serving images as base64 encoded blobs due to security concerns, including scraping.

To meet this security requirement, you are incurring a significant performance penalty, in server-side encoding energy, in file transfer and rendering time on the client.

To improve server-side performance, you can cache the encoded version; you could write $b64largeImage to disk in the same directory, check whether it exists and send it to the client.

To improve transfer time, make sure you've got GZIP enabled on the server; this *should* compress your data.

However, client side performance will remain a problem - your images will most likely not be cached on the client, and decoding the images (especially if there are 40 on each page) can consume a decent amount of CPU (especially on mobile devices).

You then get the problem that if a browser can decode the image, and attakcer/scraper can too, and they can store a copy of that image. So, all that effort doesn't *really* buy you very much secrecy.

Of course, you may want to avoid having a 3rd party embedding your images in their pages, or you may want to avoid having them scrape your images easily.

In that case, you may want to focus on having URLs that are hard/impossible to guess, or expire. This will hurt your SEO, so it's a trade-off. S3 has expiring URLs, or you could create a service which checks the referrer for each request and only honours image requests from white-listed domains, or create your own expiring image URL service - but in each case, you'd serve JPEG/GIF/PNG images so you get small file sizes and limited decoding time.