# How to use the value of <div id =last_relay1></div> for create a loop condition in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a JS file that goes to my database and return the value,
The only values that can exist are 0 and 1.

After this I go to an PHP file I invoke this value however I want create a if condition loop to analyze the value of this div for display an image depending of the value.
For example:

```
if (<div id="last_relay1"></div> = 0) then display IMAGE A
else 
if (<div id="last_relay1"></div> = 1) then display IMAGE B
```

My difficulty is to use the value of  as a PHP variable.

```js
    //Script to load the value of the current relay
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
        $("#last_relay1").load('last_update.php #RELAY1_STATUS_last_update')

        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
//little code to display the value of LAST_RELAY1 for database.
//the values returned possibles are 0 and 1
<div id="last_relay1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function with `.load()` to check the text of the DIV after it has been loaded. Use `.text()` to get the contents of the DIV.

```
$("#last_relay1").load('last_update.php #RELAY1_STATUS_last_update', function() {
    if ($this).text().trim() == "0") {
        $("#image").prop("src", "imageA.png");
    } else {
        $("#image").prop("src", "imageB.png");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking to do is to send data from the web page (generated by JavaScript) to PHP to decide which image to serve.

The way you framed the question won't help you find a solution (http://xyproblem.info/).

Instead, you will need to either:

1. [preload both image A and image b](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/), and display the one you want in javascript by unhiding it.
2. Dynamically [load the image using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-an-image) by making an [XHR request](https://gist.github.com/graylikeme/867848) that returns the correct image.

Comment: I don't think his issue is with how to display the images, it's the logic of testing the returned value of the DIV.

Comment: Well, it sounded to me like the div is an indirection for a condition that is decided by javascript, that is sent to php to decide what image to send.

Comment: I think it's the other way around, PHP returns different DIVs and that's the condition for loading the images.

Comment: I'll let the OP decide. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I follow the tip provided by Barmar.

I used the following code...

```
var value = $("#last_relay1").load('last_update.php #RELAY1_STATUS_last_update', function() {
    var value_to_test = value.text();   
    if(value_to_test == 1){
        $("#last_relay1").empty(); 
        $('<img src="img/ON.png">').appendTo("#last_relay1");           }
    else {
        $('<img src="img/OFF.png">').appendTo("#last_relay1");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you empty `#last_relay1`? And why do you only do that when it's `1`?

Comment: I empty the #last_relay1 because in HTML it shows the value 1 and the image. I only want display the image. This was a clever way of clear the value 1 or 0. The two states available   are 1=ON and 0= OFF, so if isn't value 1 = ON must be the state OFF. I hope clear your doubt.

Comment: But you only empty it when it's 1, not when it's 0.

Comment: You're also missing `}` before `else`.

Comment: Why are you putting the AJAX response into the DIV if you don't want it to show? Why not just put it in a variable and test that?