# How to display images from folder and fetch path from database using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I already have modal where I fetched the image path from the database and it is shown in the modal.
The PHP code to display images:

```
<?php

include_once '../../php/connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM img_info LEFT JOIN estate_infos ON img_info.estate_infos_id = estate_infos.id
where img_info.estate_infos_id = $mdoalid";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$datas = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($datas as $key => $data) 
{
   $pic = $data['image'];
?>

<img src="../<?php echo $pic ?>" width="360" height="150">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-imgid="<?php echo $data['img_id']; ?>">
<i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red"></i>
</a>

<?php
  }
?>
```

The Output of the above code is

[image: The Output of the above code is]

How can I implement this in AJAX?

PS: I just need to display the image, not upload and display.

Comment: Write a PHP script whose sole purpose is to look in the database for an image path, and return it _as an image_ rather than trying to make that happen as part of your webpage response. Static assets (fonts, images, css, JS scripts etc) are all different content from your page HTML.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans not necessary but i would appriciate a short example if you dont mind.

Comment: That's also what Stackoverflow is for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353850/serve-image-with-php-script-vs-direct-loading-an-image (you have a PHP script whose only role is to respond with image data) so that your page-generating script _only_ generates your HTML, with `<img src="./image.php?id=....">` instead of what you're doing now, so that the browser will simply load those image urls and get what it thinks is perfectly normal images, even if on your end, your script accesses a database, gets the image bytecode, and returns it with the correct mimetype, without ever being a "file".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your purpose by creating a script to find and return the data. After getting the data you can build your list with javascript.

```
<?php
include_once '../../php/connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM img_info LEFT JOIN estate_infos ONimg_info.estate_infos_id = estate_infos.id where img_info.estate_infos_id = $mdoalid";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
$datas = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
// Turning your array into json
echo json_encode($datas);
?>
```

On this following page, you can understand how to display your data with javascript.
https://jsfiddle.net/onury/kBQdS/

Comment: I'd suggest to use a placeholder in query string in order to prevent SQL injection: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp